# Enabling prompt-free RDP Console session in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-registry, group-policy, gpedit

I have a version of Windows 7 Home Premium that's had termserv.dll patched to allow RDP. This works fine, but what I'd like to do is allow RDP sessions to view the console session without require confirmation on the console (this is for remote control of an HTPC).

The information I've found leads me through a Group Policy Editor path to enable this, but the name of the setting seems to have changed between Win 2003 (which is what I found the instructions for) and Win 7. Additionally, Home Premium doesn't include gpedit.msc so I'm going to have to change the appropriate registry values by hand.

What do I have to change in the registry to allow prompt-free RDP Console sessions in Windows 7 Home Premium?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [LogMeIn Free](http://www.logmein.com)? This would require an internet connection but will give you console access remotely in a package that just works.